# How to check if a certain express middleware (like body-parser or express-session) is available at runtime?

Tags: express

I'm writing some middleware that depends on `body-parser` and `express-session` middleware. I want to check that those are present to produce a log error / warning so that the user of my middleware realizes that it's misconfigured. How can I check that they are present in the middleware "chain"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a general way to check for the presence of a given middleware, but if the middleware adds things to `req` or `res` you can check if they are present.

In the specific case of `body-parser` you can check for `req.body` (if `undefined` then body-parser is not present at all). But I don't there is way to check, for example, that specifically `bodyParser.json()` middleware is present. If `req.body` is not null it just means that some middleware is providing it **but you don't know which one**, it could be any of `bodyParser.urlencoded()`, `bodyParser.json()`, `bodyParser.raw()` or any other custom middleware.

Similarly for `expression-session` you can check for `req.session`. Again, there is no guarantees that it's provided by the specific middleware that you want.

So your middleware could look like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // pretend that is a middleware from a another package
  if (req.body === undefined) {
    throw Error("Missing body-parser");
  }
  if (req.session == undefined) {
    throw Error("Missing express-session")
  }
  next()
});
```

The same example on an express app:

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var morgan = require('morgan')
const winston = require('winston');
const { format } = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session')

var sess = {
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {}
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
  sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies
}


const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.splat(),
    winston.format.json()
  ),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname, "views"));

app.use(session(sess))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// YOUR OWN MIDDLEWARE HERE
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body === undefined) {
    throw Error("Missing body-parser");
  }
  if (req.session == undefined) {
    throw Error("Missing express-session")
  }
  next()
});

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  logger.info("req.body", {"req.body": req.body});
  logger.info("req.session", { "req.session": req.session});
  
  req.session.views ??= 1;
  req.session.views++;


  res.render("index", {views: req.session.views});
});

app.listen(5000, function() {
  logger.info("Web server started on port 5000")
})
```